# SUM of TotalSellPrice, Grouped by JobID? - Beginner SQL Question

Tags: sql, sum

I'm looking to write a query that gives the YTD sales for each job within our system. We use Bistrack. Here is what I have:

```
select C.Shortname AS "Customer", J.JobReference, (OH.TotalSellPrice - OH.NonSalesAmount) AS "TotalSellPrice", CIL.Amount AS "Contract Invoice", CA.Address1, CA.City, CA.TaxAreaID, T.Name AS "Tax Area", CA.PostCode AS "ZIP Code", OH.DateTimeCreated, TotalSalesYTD, J.JobID, CA.CustomerAddressID, C.CustomerID, SaleType
from dbo.CustomerAddress AS CA WITH(NOLOCK)
left join TaxArea AS T WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.TaxAreaID = T.TaxAreaID
left join Customer as C WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
left join Job as J WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CustomerAddressID = J.CustomerAddressID
left join CustomerFinancial as CF WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CustomerID = CF.CustomerID
left join OrderHeader AS OH WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CustomerAddressID = OH.DeliveryAddressID
left join ContractInvoicingLine AS CIL WITH(NOLOCK) ON OH.ContractInvoicingLineID = CIL.ContractInvoicingLineID 
WHERE TotalSalesYTD <> 0 AND OH.DateTimeCreated > '2019-12-31' AND OH.OrderStatus = 8 AND OH.SaleType = 3
ORDER BY C.ShortName, JobReference
```

This displays a result where each job reference is shown multiple times for each order under that job. I'd like to combine the orders into a SUM for each job. So, for example, I want the blue column to be a single number that is just 3362.68 + 101.03 + 1642.86 + 1298.75.

[image: Example]

My idea would be to do SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice - OH.NonSalesAmount) AS "TotalSellPrice",  but that doesn't work, seemingly because my other columns are not in the function. I think this might be something simple to fix but I just started in SQL. I have gathered that partitioning could be used from browsing this site, but I have no idea how to apply it to my current query. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  Also, simplifying the query would help others too.

Comment: Did you use a `GROUP BY` clause in your `SUM` attempt?

Comment: @EricBrandt Hey Eric, when I put "GROUP BY J.JobID" in the end of the query, this error shows up: "Column 'Customer.ShortName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message you noted in the comments above, I'm going to assume you're using SQL Server as a database appliance.

In SQL Server, and most other databases, when you use `SUM` or any other aggregate functions you are required to add a `GROUP BY` clause that includes all non-aggregated columns from the `SELECT` clause of the query.

```
SELECT 
   C.Shortname AS "Customer"
    ,J.JobReference
    ,SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice - OH.NonSalesAmount) AS "TotalSellPrice"
    ,CIL.Amount AS "Contract Invoice"
    ,CA.Address1
    ,CA.City
    ,CA.TaxAreaID
    ,T.Name AS "Tax Area"
    ,CA.PostCode AS "ZIP Code"
    ,OH.DateTimeCreated
    ,TotalSalesYTD
    ,J.JobID
    ,CA.CustomerAddressID
    ,C.CustomerID
    ,SaleType
FROM dbo.CustomerAddress AS CA 
LEFT JOIN TaxArea AS T 
  ON CA.TaxAreaID = T.TaxAreaID
LEFT JOIN Customer AS C  
  ON CA.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Job AS J  
  ON CA.CustomerAddressID = J.CustomerAddressID
LEFT JOIN CustomerFinancial AS CF  
  ON CA.CustomerID = CF.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN OrderHeader AS OH  
  ON CA.CustomerAddressID = OH.DeliveryAddressID
LEFT JOIN ContractInvoicingLine AS CIL  
  ON OH.ContractInvoicingLineID = CIL.ContractInvoicingLineID
WHERE TotalSalesYTD <> 0
    AND OH.DateTimeCreated > '2019-12-31'
    AND OH.OrderStatus = 8
    AND OH.SaleType = 3
GROUP BY
   C.Shortname
    ,J.JobReference
    ,CIL.Amount
    ,CA.Address1
    ,CA.City
    ,CA.TaxAreaID
    ,T.Name
    ,CA.PostCode
    ,OH.DateTimeCreated
    ,TotalSalesYTD
    ,J.JobID
    ,CA.CustomerAddressID
    ,C.CustomerID
    ,SaleType
ORDER BY 
   C.ShortName
    ,JobReference
```

Plus, have a look at these, and then make informed decisions.

[Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

[Is NOLOCK Ever The Right Choice?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/nolock-ever-right-choice/)

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks so much. This query helps answer my question partially. The other part is this: say I have JobID 29923 and 54630. 29923 has a two orders, where TotalSellPrice on one is 16.00 and the other 9.00. I want my query to show Job ID:29923 TotalSellPrice:23.00. I will do research on NOLOCK, I appreciate you providing.

Comment: @AveryWilson, there is nothing in your query to indicate what an "order" is, as you're using that word in your comment. In general, though, if you're grouping by an attribute (column) that you don't want to group by, you'll need to either take that attribute out of your 'SELECT` list, or wrap it in an aggregate function like `MAX` or `MIN`.

Comment: Eric- I can't see the image anymore- but if you can, you can see that for each color square, on the right there is a "JobID". That Job ID applies for all of those "Orders" (sorry for using that word, an order is just a single line in this instance. So, the blue section has 4 "Orders", the yellow has 1). But, within that JobID, there are 4 different "TotalSellPrice" numbers (ex: the first order is for $3362.68). What I want is to add all of those numbers together under a single line based on JobID. So, JobID should be the SUM of all the lines within that ID.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/s2vp68C4/sqlquestion.png here is another link in case the other one is broken

Comment: But the question is, what column(s) in your query are causing multiple rows per `JobID`? All of the unobfuscated columns are the same for all `JobID` values once the dollar amounts are summed.

Comment: I see - so my goal should be to simplify my query so that there aren't any fields getting in the way? Thanks a ton Eric.  and thanks for the advice about NOLOCK.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. Your goal should be to understand your data, and your SQL, so that you can write the query in a way that it reliably returns the results that you need. That may mean making the query more complex, or maybe simpler, but you'll find that out as you work with the data.